# Why does it display "at-rule or selector expectedcss" when using this CSS?

Tags: html, css, scss-mixins

I am trying to implement a shape but when I add this CSS code it shows an error:
[https://codepen.io/rayfranco/pen/Llvbt](https://codepen.io/alexerlandsson/pen/ZvXVbB)

```
  &:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  &:hover { 
    .hex:last-child {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    .hex:first-child {
      opacity: 1;      
      div:before, div:after {
        height: $borderHover;
      }     
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }
  }
```

The error is located at the `$` sign.

> at-rule or selector expectedcss(css-ruleorselectorexpected)

Comment: The codepen you referred to doesn’t contain that code. You need to show us _where_ you tried to insert this exactly, how else are we supposed to be able what you might have done wrong?

Comment: @CBroe what do you mean it doesnt contain? I am having problem with $ sign, no matter what code I use. The editor shows an error on that sign all the time.

Comment: _“The editor shows an error on that sign all the time.”_ - where? I don’t see any.